# Checking the input of the selected time in the time interval

Tags: python, django

I have a time interval from 09: 00 to 23: 00. I choose any time. How do I determine if this time is included in my interval?

Comment: `result = time_start < time_given < time_end`?

Comment: Changed the question. The time can be either 08: 00 or 00: 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the datetime module you can do it this way:

```
def convert_hour_to_min(x):
  x = x.split(":")
  minute = int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1])
  return minute
interval_1 = convert_hour_to_min("09:00") 
interval_2 = convert_hour_to_min("23:00")
random_time = convert_hour_to_min("8:30")
if interval_1 < random_time < interval_2:
  print("True")
else:
  print("False")
```